# Can't install gtk-mac-integration

Tags: macos, haskell, gtk, cabal, leksah

I don't understand the error because it appears to be requiring a version of the same package that I'm trying to install.

```
$ cabal install gtk-mac-integration
Resolving dependencies...
[1 of 2] Compiling SetupWrapper     ( /var/folders/cU/cUDMo9+9Gl817+j+h1DAvk+++TI/-Tmp-/gtk-mac-integration-0.1.0.46479/gtk-mac-integration-0.1.0.4/SetupWrapper.hs, /var/folders/cU/cUDMo9+9Gl817+j+h1DAvk+++TI/-Tmp-/gtk-mac-integration-0.1.0.46479/gtk-mac-integration-0.1.0.4/dist/setup/SetupWrapper.o )
[2 of 2] Compiling Main             ( /var/folders/cU/cUDMo9+9Gl817+j+h1DAvk+++TI/-Tmp-/gtk-mac-integration-0.1.0.46479/gtk-mac-integration-0.1.0.4/Setup.hs, /var/folders/cU/cUDMo9+9Gl817+j+h1DAvk+++TI/-Tmp-/gtk-mac-integration-0.1.0.46479/gtk-mac-integration-0.1.0.4/dist/setup/Main.o )
Linking /var/folders/cU/cUDMo9+9Gl817+j+h1DAvk+++TI/-Tmp-/gtk-mac-integration-0.1.0.46479/gtk-mac-integration-0.1.0.4/dist/setup/setup ...
[1 of 2] Compiling Gtk2HsSetup      ( Gtk2HsSetup.hs, dist/setup-wrapper/Gtk2HsSetup.o )
[2 of 2] Compiling Main             ( SetupMain.hs, dist/setup-wrapper/Main.o )
Linking dist/setup-wrapper/setup ...
Configuring gtk-mac-integration-0.1.0.4...
setup: The pkg-config package gtk-mac-integration version >=0.9.6 is required
but it could not be found.
cabal: Error: some packages failed to install:
gtk-mac-integration-0.1.0.4 failed during the configure step. The exception
was:
ExitFailure 1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't want the Haskell package `gtk-mac-integration`, it wants the *system* package `gtk-mac-integration`. That is, the Haskell package you're trying to install is just a binding to the `gtk-mac-integration` library (which I think is bundled with GTK+); you'll have to install it separately before you can install the Haskell package.

If you already have GTK+ installed, then the problem is that the `pkg-config` tool Cabal uses to find external library dependencies can't find the corresponding `.pc` files for the library. I don't know how to fix that, though; at least not without more details.

Comment: yes, I already have a version of gtk installed, but it is older. I will try updating gtk, if I can work out how I installed it in the first place.

Comment: Struggling to get gtk+ updated. With $ ~/.local/bin/jhbuild build  meta-gtk-osx-core, I get the error:   *** Error during phase configure of gtk+: ########## Error running autoreconf -fis && ./configure --prefix /Users/peter/gtk/inst --libdir '/Users/peter/gtk/inst/lib' --with-gdktarget=quartz --enable-quartz-relocation  *** [12/14]

Comment: Unfortunately, compiling GTK+ is well outside my area of expertise. I suggest asking another question (possibly on Super User? I'm not sure).